How do I constrain several fit parameters to sum together to 1 while fitting a biexponential in python?
I have some decay data that looks like it could be biexponential so I want to fit it to the equation of y(t) = y0 + a1e^(-k1t) + a2e^(-k2t), while fitting the parameters of y0, a1, k1, a2, and k2. I can get a decent fit, but based on the physical system I am analyzing the parameters of y0, a1, and a2 should sum together to equal 1, with all three being positive values. Is there a way I can do this?
I tried this and it does a decent fit, but doesn't force a1 + a2 + y0 = 1.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

nai=np.array([
[1.22212386e+00, 3.29623401e+01, 6.47035556e+01, 9.64437723e+01,
 1.28183988e+02, 1.59925204e+02, 1.91665421e+02, 2.23405636e+02,
 2.55145451e+02, 2.86886261e+02, 3.18627075e+02, 3.50366878e+02,
 3.82106686e+02, 4.13846500e+02, 4.45586303e+02, 4.77327118e+02,
 5.09067921e+02, 5.40807729e+02, 5.72547538e+02, 6.04287346e+02,
 6.36027155e+02, 6.67767964e+02, 6.99507773e+02, 7.31248581e+02,
 7.62988390e+02, 7.94728199e+02, 8.26468997e+02, 8.58208596e+02,
 8.89948201e+02, 9.21687811e+02, 9.53428532e+02, 9.85169347e+02,
 1.01690915e+03, 1.04864896e+03, 1.08038877e+03, 1.11212858e+03,
 1.14386839e+03, 1.17561019e+03, 1.20735000e+03, 1.23908982e+03,
 1.27082962e+03, 1.30256943e+03, 1.33431024e+03, 1.36605004e+03,
 1.39779085e+03, 1.42953066e+03, 1.46127048e+03, 1.49301128e+03,
 1.52475109e+03, 1.55649076e+03, 1.58823037e+03, 1.61997097e+03,
 1.65171057e+03, 1.68345118e+03, 1.71519078e+03, 1.74693039e+03,
 1.77866999e+03, 1.81040960e+03], 
[1.,         0.92072946, 0.93392534, 0.92599632, 0.84650909,     0.89966649,
 0.85375192, 0.8359797,  0.81487989, 0.83947038, 0.78711305, 0.77231505,
 0.74861849, 0.67860406, 0.73989558, 0.78446446, 0.72500833, 0.72903779,
 0.69205116, 0.73345758, 0.71143277, 0.71248356, 0.67470885, 0.67626045,
 0.63480034, 0.68824323, 0.69961798, 0.68302773, 0.64354886, 0.64451215,
 0.63644302, 0.63616151, 0.63049777, 0.62942254, 0.67511705, 0.62839769,
 0.61536734, 0.58931514, 0.60952486, 0.59674224, 0.55770579, 0.58915328,
 0.5567563 , 0.58849712, 0.50377624, 0.50890445, 0.5446239,  0.51436443,
 0.52945348, 0.55326716, 0.51701847, 0.5240366,  0.54487462, 0.50567212,
 0.49233296, 0.5107218,  0.56567484, 0.48162376]])

#%%biexponential decay
# Define the biexponential decay function with a1 + a2 + y0 = 1


nai=nai.astype(np.float64)

def biexponential_decay(nai, a1, k1, a2, k2, y0):
    y0 = 1 - a1 - a2
    return a1 * np.exp(-k1 * nai[0]) + a2 * np.exp(-k2 * nai[0]) + y0

# Define bounds for parameters
bounds = ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1])  # Lower and upper bounds for a1, k1, a2, k2, and y0

# Fit the curve to the data
params, covariance = curve_fit(biexponential_decay, nai, nai[1], p0=(0.5, .001, 0.3, .001, .2), bounds=bounds, method='trf')  # Providing initial parameters as p0

# Extract the fitted parameters
a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit, y0_fit = params

# Calculate the residuals
residuals = nai[1] - biexponential_decay(nai, a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit, y0_fit)

# Calculate the mean squared error
mse = np.mean(residuals**2)

# Calculate the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix
cov_diag = np.diag(covariance)

# Calculate the standard error on the fitted values
std_error = np.sqrt(mse * cov_diag)

# Display the fitted parameters, R-squared value, and standard errors
print("Fitted Parameters:")
print("a1 =", a1_fit)
print("k1 =", k1_fit)
print("a2 =", a2_fit)
print("k2 =", k2_fit)
print("y0 =", y0_fit)
print("R-squared:", 1 - mse / np.var(nai[1]))
print("Standard Errors:", std_error)

# Generate the fitted curve using the fitted parameters
y_fit = biexponential_decay(nai, a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit, y0_fit)

# Plot the original data and the fitted curve
plt.scatter(nai[0], nai[1], label='Original Data')
plt.plot(nai[0], y_fit, 'r-', label='Fitted Curve')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('nai[0]')
plt.ylabel('nai[1]')
plt.show()


You already have y0 = 1 - a1 - a2 inside biexponential_decay and the y0 parameter actually is ignored. So remove y0 as parameter.

Even when I try that, it makes it so that y0 is below zero, which is something I also want to avoid.

Does it mean that what you have chosen as model to approximate the data does not cover the actual values, but you try to stick to it?

Maybe? I have similar data sets taken using the same procedure that all end up being fit pretty well to this curve, but it is this particular set of data that is making it not work the way it should.

It is totally possible to solve your problem with scipy.
See the scipy.optimize.minimize method that allows to minimize objective function while enforcing bounds and constraints on parameters.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

Lets rewrite your problem the following way. First we state your model:
def model(x, y0, a1, k1, a2, k2):
    return y0 + a1 * np.exp(-k1 * x) + a2 * np.exp(-k2 * x)

Then we build a function that will constraint your variable to sum up to unity, constraint should be of the form of C(p) = 0:
def constraint(p):
    return p[0] + p[1] + p[3] - 1.  # Equivalent to: y0 + a1 + a2 = 1

Now we construct a wrapper to express the least square formulation in order to minimize it:
def factory(x, y, model):
    def wrapped(p):
        return 0.5 * np.sum(np.power((y - model(x, *p)), 2))
    return wrapped

objective = factory(x, y, model)

Where x and y are your respective data. At this point everything is ready for minimizing our objective function with respect to your boundaries and constraint.
sol = optimize.minimize(
    objective,
    x0=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    bounds=[(0., np.inf)]*5,
    constraints=[{"type": "eq", "fun": constraint}]
)
 # message: Optimization terminated successfully
 # success: True
 #  status: 0
 #     fun: 0.019907739276457715
 #       x: [ 9.223e-02  1.463e-01  6.761e-03  7.615e-01  3.479e-04]
 #     nit: 53
 #     jac: [ 1.569e-02  1.867e-02 -1.349e-02  1.672e-02  2.817e+00]
 #    nfev: 332
 #    njev: 53

We can confirm your constraint is met:
constraint(sol.x)  # 0.0

So at this stage, solver converged and your constraint is satisfied. Lets examine the solution:
yhat = model(x, *sol.x)
score = r2_score(y, yhat)  # 0.9581254317380687

And visually:
xlin = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200)
ylin = model(xlin, *sol.x)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.scatter(x, y)
axe.plot(xlin, ylin)
axe.grid()



With the model equation  y(t) = y0 + a1e^(-k1t) + a2e^(-k2t) note that y(0) is not equal to y0.
The specified condition y0+a1+a2=1 implies y0<0 since a1+a2>1. This would be contradictary if y0 was >0 since a1+a2>1.
Remember that y(0) is not y0. As expected y(0)=1.
I tried with a different software. The fitting is satisfactory :


Then y0=0 and a2=1-a1. In this case simply fit the function y(t) =  a1e^(-k1t) + (1-a1)e^(-k2t).

y(0) = y0 + a1 + a2 as exponential terms are equal to 1. Could you explain a bit more why you think that a1 + a2 > 1? It appears it is possible to solve this regression problem with all parameters being positive and summing up to unity.

First of all I would check that you really need y0 to be positive. I presume that that is to maintain positivity for large x, but your data doesn't actually get anywhere near that. You get quite a good curve fit with a2 slightly larger than 1 and y0 slightly negative.
However, if you do need to enforce a constraint then one fudge to enforce it is simply to add a massive penalty to your fitting function when that constraint isn't satisfied.
Here, I do as @mkrieger1 suggests and remove y0 as a parameter, simply setting it to 1-a1-a2. Your function with a penalty applied is
def biexponential_decay(nai, a1, k1, a2, k2):
    y0 = 1 - a1 - a2
    penalty = 0
    if y0 < 0 : penalty = 1000000
    return a1 * np.exp(-k1 * nai[0]) + a2 * np.exp(-k2 * nai[0]) + y0 + penalty


To all intents and purposes, if y0 is constrained not to be negative (or, equivalently, a1+a2<=1) then the best fit to the data would probably have y0=0.
Fitted Parameters:
a1 = 0.15346342751410955
k1 = 0.00647572574481048
a2 = 0.8465352091104801
k2 = 0.0002945049705031798
y0 = 1.363375410345924e-06
R-squared: 0.9582009677718569
Standard Errors: [1.60315165e-03 8.42485320e-05 2.00306402e-02 1.06429003e-05]

For reference, the full code (amended to remove a non-used import and remove y0 throughout as a parameter) is
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

nai=np.array([
[1.22212386e+00, 3.29623401e+01, 6.47035556e+01, 9.64437723e+01,
 1.28183988e+02, 1.59925204e+02, 1.91665421e+02, 2.23405636e+02,
 2.55145451e+02, 2.86886261e+02, 3.18627075e+02, 3.50366878e+02,
 3.82106686e+02, 4.13846500e+02, 4.45586303e+02, 4.77327118e+02,
 5.09067921e+02, 5.40807729e+02, 5.72547538e+02, 6.04287346e+02,
 6.36027155e+02, 6.67767964e+02, 6.99507773e+02, 7.31248581e+02,
 7.62988390e+02, 7.94728199e+02, 8.26468997e+02, 8.58208596e+02,
 8.89948201e+02, 9.21687811e+02, 9.53428532e+02, 9.85169347e+02,
 1.01690915e+03, 1.04864896e+03, 1.08038877e+03, 1.11212858e+03,
 1.14386839e+03, 1.17561019e+03, 1.20735000e+03, 1.23908982e+03,
 1.27082962e+03, 1.30256943e+03, 1.33431024e+03, 1.36605004e+03,
 1.39779085e+03, 1.42953066e+03, 1.46127048e+03, 1.49301128e+03,
 1.52475109e+03, 1.55649076e+03, 1.58823037e+03, 1.61997097e+03,
 1.65171057e+03, 1.68345118e+03, 1.71519078e+03, 1.74693039e+03,
 1.77866999e+03, 1.81040960e+03], 
[1.,         0.92072946, 0.93392534, 0.92599632, 0.84650909,     0.89966649,
 0.85375192, 0.8359797,  0.81487989, 0.83947038, 0.78711305, 0.77231505,
 0.74861849, 0.67860406, 0.73989558, 0.78446446, 0.72500833, 0.72903779,
 0.69205116, 0.73345758, 0.71143277, 0.71248356, 0.67470885, 0.67626045,
 0.63480034, 0.68824323, 0.69961798, 0.68302773, 0.64354886, 0.64451215,
 0.63644302, 0.63616151, 0.63049777, 0.62942254, 0.67511705, 0.62839769,
 0.61536734, 0.58931514, 0.60952486, 0.59674224, 0.55770579, 0.58915328,
 0.5567563 , 0.58849712, 0.50377624, 0.50890445, 0.5446239,  0.51436443,
 0.52945348, 0.55326716, 0.51701847, 0.5240366,  0.54487462, 0.50567212,
 0.49233296, 0.5107218,  0.56567484, 0.48162376]])

#%%biexponential decay
# Define the biexponential decay function with a1 + a2 + y0 = 1


nai=nai.astype(np.float64)

def biexponential_decay(nai, a1, k1, a2, k2):
    y0 = 1 - a1 - a2
    penalty = 0
    if y0 < 0 : penalty = 1000000
    return a1 * np.exp(-k1 * nai[0]) + a2 * np.exp(-k2 * nai[0]) + y0 + penalty

# Define bounds for parameters
bounds = ([0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 2, 1])  # Lower and upper bounds for a1, k1, a2, k2

# Fit the curve to the data
params, covariance = curve_fit(biexponential_decay, nai, nai[1], p0=(0.5, .001, 0.3, .001), bounds=bounds)  # Providing initial parameters as p0

# Extract the fitted parameters
a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit = params

# Calculate the residuals
residuals = nai[1] - biexponential_decay(nai, a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit)

# Calculate the mean squared error
mse = np.mean(residuals**2)

# Calculate the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix
cov_diag = np.diag(covariance)

# Calculate the standard error on the fitted values
std_error = np.sqrt(mse * cov_diag)

# Display the fitted parameters, R-squared value, and standard errors
print("Fitted Parameters:")
print("a1 =", a1_fit)
print("k1 =", k1_fit)
print("a2 =", a2_fit)
print("k2 =", k2_fit)
print("y0 =", 1-a1_fit-a2_fit)
print("R-squared:", 1 - mse / np.var(nai[1]))
print("Standard Errors:", std_error)

# Generate the fitted curve using the fitted parameters
y_fit = biexponential_decay(nai, a1_fit, k1_fit, a2_fit, k2_fit)

# Plot the original data and the fitted curve
plt.scatter(nai[0], nai[1], label='Original Data')
plt.plot(nai[0], y_fit, 'r-', label='Fitted Curve')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('nai[0]')
plt.ylabel('nai[1]')
plt.show()

